# Change a state value in a React testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have the following component:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export function MyComponent() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      big container
      <button onClick={() => setVal(!val)}>click</button>
      {val && <div>small container</div>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

There is a [div](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Other_block_elements) containing the text "small container", which only appears when `val` is `true`.

I want to write a test in [Jest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jest_(framework)) for this, but how can I mock the value of `val` there?

Here is my code so far:

```
  it('small container visible only when val is true', () => {
    const { queryByText } = render(<MyComponent />);
    const toTest = queryByText('small container');
    expect(toTest).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

This test passes, but how can the added `val` be set to `true` in order to test that `toTest` is present in the document?

Comment: You _don't_ mock the state value. You interact with the component such that its state changes, _just as a user would_. One of the major advantages of RTL vs e.g. Enzyme is that it doesn't offer footguns like access to a component's state: https://testing-library.com/docs/guiding-principles/.

Answer (score 0):

You can click the button which will set the `val` to true.

```
it('small container visible only when val is true', () => {
  const {queryByText, getByTestId} = render(<MyComponent />);
  const clickButton = getByTestId('your.button.test.id');
  fireEvent.click(clickButton);
  expect(queryByText('small container')).toBeInDocument();
});
```

React testing library does not recommend to test implementation details as per [documented](https://testing-library.com/docs/#what-you-should-avoid-with-testing-library) here. That's why you might not want to access internal state of component while testing.

Comment: Are there a misunderstanding, I don't think it's wrong to click a button